# LinkedIn API Publish in a Group

Tags: python-3.x

I have this Python code and it tells me that it has published correctly and gives me the {"id":"urn:li:ugcPost:XXXXXX"}', but I can't find the publication anywhere in the group. I have tried in a group that I own as well as in a public group, the result is the same, OK, but the publication does not appear anywhere. What could be going wrong? Here is the code I am using.

```
# Mensaje a publicar
text = f"Unete a nuestro nuevo canal de noticias de Telegram: https://t.me/dciberseguridad y mas"

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts'


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

payload = {
    "author": "urn:li:person:"+profile_id, 
    "containerEntity": "urn:li:group"+group_id, 
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": text
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
            "media": [
                {
                    "status": "READY",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "Descripción de la imagen"
                    },
                    "media": 'urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:D4D10AQEUQXI_LELXnw'
                        
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
print(response.content)

# Comprobación del código de estado de la respuesta
if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Publicación exitosa en LinkedIn!")
else:
    print(f"Error al publicar en LinkedIn: {response.content}")
```

Comment: Try asking at LinkedIn, as this seems to be an API problem?

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't thought of that. I've already sent them an email to see what they say because it's strange that everything seems to be OK, but it's not showing up anywhere. Nevertheless, if anyone has experienced this before and can shed some light on it, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: Finaly i found the problem, in this line

"com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"

No is PUBLIC is 
"com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "CONTAINER"